# Desktop resolution does not fit the display

Tags: nvidia, display, kde, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 20.0.3 on a Dell Vostro. After it froze, I restarted it, logged into KDE  with the correct resolution. But after the successful login, the desktop size becomes about 20% bigger and does not fit the screen. It scrolls vertically and horizontally. But the resolution it shows is 1366x768 and the Refresh rate to be 60hz, as it was before. How can I get back the desktop that fits the display? Thank you.

Comment: What actually is the resolution ?

Comment: `xrandr -s 1000x500` (change `1000×500`) This command will help you to change the resolution

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.config/monitors.xml` This command may also help